# Active Record must have domain logic?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, activerecord, yii

I started some time working with the Yii Framework and I saw some things "do not let me sleep." Here I talk about my doubts about how Yii users use the Active Record.

I saw many people add business rules of the application directly in Active Record, the same generated by [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii). I deeply believe that this is a misinterpretation of what is Active Record and a violation of [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

> [Early on, SRP is easier to apply. ActiveRecord classes handle persistence, associations and not much else. But bit-by-bit, they grow. Objects that are inherently responsible for persistence become the de facto owner of all business logic as well. And a year or two later you have a User class with over 500 lines of code, and hundreds of methods in it’s public interface. Callback hell ensues.](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/)

When I talked about it with some people and my view was criticized. But when asked:

And when you need to regenerate your Active Record full of business rules through Gii what do you do? Rewrite? Copy and Paste? That's great, congratulations!

Got an answer, only the silence.

**So, I:**

What I am currently doing in order to reach a little better architecture is to generate the Active Records in a folder /ar. And inside the /models folder add the Domain Model.

By the way, is the Domain Model who owns the business rules, and is the Domain Model that uses the Active Records to persist and retrieve data, and this is the Data Model.

What do you think of this approach?
If I'm wrong somewhere, please tell me why before criticizing harshly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the comments on this article are quite helpful:
http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

In particular, the idea that your models should grow out of a strictly 'fat model' setup as you need more seems quite wise.

Are you having issues now or mainly trying to plan ahead? This may be hard to plan ahead for and may just need refactoring as you go ...

**Edit:**

Regarding `moveUserToGroup` (in your comment below), I could see how having that might bother you.  Found this as I was thinking about your question: https://gist.github.com/justinko/2838490 An equivalent setup that you might use for your `moveUserToGroup` would be a [CFormModel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormModel) subclass.  It'll give you the ability to do validations, etc, but could then be more specific to what you're trying to handle (and use multiple AR objects to achieve your objectives instead of just one).

I often use [CFormModel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormModel) to handle forms that have multiple AR objects or forms where I want to do other things.

Sounds like that may be what you're after.  More details available here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.overview

Comment: My problem now is that my Active Records are automatically generated. So, if I put domain rules into, when I regenerate this rules are lost. This code generation is not a merge, is delete a file and create a new. And I need to do it constantly, because the entities in the database has changed constantly.

Comment: Two questions. 1) Have you looked at the way GiiX works? Might be beneficial for your rebuilds. 2) have you considered reworking your architecture? Having *no* logic in your models is going to severely hamper you long-term. There is generally a need for *some* logic in your models ...

Comment: 1) No. But, I'll take a look. 2) Yes. I finished with my question: What do you think of this approach.

Comment: To complement: What is bothering me is to have a User class, a method relations() and moveUserToGroup($group) for example. It sounds like they are totally different things. This is correct from the standpoint of object-oriented?

Comment: It's what I do. In the folder /ar I have Active Records and /models I have, say, Business Models. The only difference is that in my classes /models do not extend any other, as are the application domain. Just instantiate ActiveRecords or /forms eg UserForm - which are extensions CFormModel. What do you think?

Comment: Seems reasonable. Other items you may want to look into are Yii components. We've found them quite helpful and you can build pluggable versions (where you have a main item that can be swapped out for child classes - like the Yii DB component). They're quite powerful.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of Active Record, according to Martin Fowler:

> An object carries both data and behavior. Much of this data is persistent and needs to be stored in a database. Active Record uses the most obvious approach, putting data access logic in the domain object. This way all people know how to read and write their data to and from the database.

When you segregate data and behavior you no longer have an Active Record. Two common related patterns are Data Mapper and Table/Row Gateway (this one more related to RDBMS's).

Again, Fowler says:

> The Data Mapper is a layer of software that separates the in-memory objects from the database. Its responsibility is to transfer data between the two and also to isolate them from each other. With Data Mapper the in-memory objects needn't know even that there's a database present; they need no SQL interface code, and certainly no knowledge of the database schema.

And again:

> A Table Data Gateway holds all the SQL for accessing a single table or view: selects, inserts, updates, and deletes. Other code calls its methods for all interaction with the database.
>
> A Row Data Gateway gives you objects that look exactly like the record in your record structure but can be accessed with the regular mechanisms of your programming language. All details of data source access are hidden behind this interface.

A Data Mapper is usualy storage independent, the mapper recovers data from the storage and creates mapped objects (Plain-old objects). The mapped object knows absolutely nothing about being stored somewhere else.

As I said, TDG/RDG are more inwardly related to a relational table. TDG object represents the structure of the table and implements all common operations. RGD object contains data related to one single row of the table. Unlike mapped object of Data Mapper, the RDG object has conscience that it is part of a whole, because it references its container TDG.